A comprehensive Pokémon animé, movies, specials, shorts, etc. watch order
I've looked around the internet, but I cannot seem to find a truly comprehensive canon-order watch order of all Pokémon animé content. I'm looking for an order of Pokémon episodes, spinoff episodes, movies, specials, shorts, and so on which follows the in-universe chronological order of the story. If that is difficult to precisely determine (as in the case of some Pikachu shorts, for example), original release order is an acceptable substitute. I would also like to include all banned/undubbed episodes or any other content only produced in Japan.
A good answer to this question would include either such a list or a link to one if it exists somewhere and I have just been unable to find it.

An example of a list that is almost, but not quite, what I'm looking for: https://www.gamesradar.com/how-to-watch-pokemon-in-order-tv-show-movies/

Can you clarify what's missing from, or otherwise unsatisfactory about the Gamesradar article?

That's difficult, because 2011-07-16 saw the release of two Pokémon movies that both take place at the exact same time in alternate universes, so you'd have to watch them simultaneously.

@F1Krazy though it briefly mentions things like the Chronicles and Pikachu Shorts, it fails to include those in the order. It also does not specifically mention banned episodes (obviously those are part of a season, but they're easy to miss if you don't know about them)

I'm using the Japanese version. Keep in mind that things are a bit different for international releases. Episodes might be missing, they might be put in different order or in entirely different releases, movies might be cut up etc. etc.
For the first season it looks like this:



Year
Episodes
Season
Title




1997
1-48 of 276
OG
Pocket Monsters


1998
1
MV01
Mewtwo no Gyakushuu



49-77 of 276
OG



1998
2
SP
Pikachuu no Fuyuyasumi



78-106 of 276
OG



1999
1
MV02
Maboroshi no Pokémon Lugia Bakutan



107-128 of 276
OG



1999
2
SP
Pikachuu no Fuyuyasumi 2000



129-130 of 276
OG



2000
1
SP
Yadoking no Ichinichi



130-157 of 276
OG



2000
1
MV03
Kesshoutou no Teiou Entei



158-168 of 276
OG



2000
3
SP
TV-ban Pocket Monsters Special Masara Town Hen Soushuuhen



168-180 of 276
OG



2000
3
SP
Pichuu to Pikachuu no Fuyuyasumi 2001


2000
1
SP
Mewtwo! Ware wa Koko ni Ari



180-207 of 276
OG



2001
1
MV04
Celebi Toki o Koeta Deai



207-232 of 276
OG



2001
1
SP
Pocket Monsters Crystal: Raikou Ikazuchi no Densetsu



232-258 of 276
OG



2002
1
MV05
Mizu no Miyako no Mamorigami Latias to Latios



258-276 of 276
OG




